# Extend a given shape from the UML-TikZ package with the path picture property

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, pgfkeys, tikz-uml

I call the style definition `mystyle` in line 20. As you can see, I pass a `\filldraw` command as an argument to the style definition `mystyle`. That way I want to achieve a gray circle to be displayed in the middle of the transition line. Unfortunately it does not work.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, calc, shadings, shadows, shapes.arrows, arrows.meta, matrix, mindmap}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    mystyle/.style n args = {1}{
        color=black,
        rounded corners, 
        arrows={-Straight Barb[angle=60:9pt 3]},
        path picture={
            #1
        }
    }]
    \begin{umlstate}[name=Statemaschine]{Lightcontrol}
        \umlstateinitial[name=start, x=0,y=3]{start}
        \umlbasicstate [fill=red!20, width=5cm] {manual}
        \umlbasicstate [below left=4of manual,fill=red!20, width=5cm,] {waiting}
        \umlbasicstate [below right=4of manual,fill=red!20, width=5cm] {auto}
        \umlbasicstate [below=8of manual,fill=red!20, width=5cm] {time}
        \umltrans[mystyle={\filldraw [gray] (0,0) circle [radius=9pt]}]{waiting}{auto}
    \end{umlstate}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There's a `;` missing in your path specification.

Comment: do you mean like this: \umltrans[mystyle={\filldraw [gray] (0,0) circle [radius=9pt];}]{waiting}{auto}

Comment: Yes, however, your document already doesn't compile for me even without `mystyle`. I need at least `/tikz/below left` and so on. Hoewever `\umltrans` still throws an error without `mystyle`.

Comment: i have the tikz-uml.sty library in the same directory. Unfortunately it does not work even with semicolon. The following error message appears: Package pgfkeys: I do not know the key '/tikz/0) circle [radius', to which you passed '9pt];', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you mispelled it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `insert path` between the two states.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, calc, shadings, shadows, shapes.arrows, arrows.meta, matrix, mindmap}

\usepackage{tikz-uml}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        mystyle/.style  2 args = {%
            color=black,
            rounded corners, 
            arrows={-Straight Barb[angle=60:9pt 3]},
            insert path={node[circle, fill=gray!60,minimum size=12pt] at  ($(#1)!.5!(#2)$){}},
        }]
        \begin{umlstate}[name=Statemaschine]{Lightcontrol}
            \umlstateinitial[name=start, x=0,y=3]{start}
            \umlbasicstate [fill=red!20, width=5cm] {manual}
            \umlbasicstate [below left=4 of manual,fill=red!20, width=5cm,] {waiting}
            \umlbasicstate [below right=4 of manual,fill=red!20, width=5cm] {auto}
            \umlbasicstate [below=8 of manual,fill=red!20, width=5cm] {time}
            \umltrans[mystyle={waiting}{auto}]{waiting}{auto} % changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        \end{umlstate}
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{document}
```